# Flash Actionscript 3 - sound seeking/playing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an audio file which is 4 hours long. I created a standart player to manage my needs - works fine, but you dont seek more than 12180000 miliseconds in position count player stops. If you position the sound to play 12100000 (few seconds earlyear) - plays fine and if it countinues to play without changing the position by code, it is good till the end. I dont get any errors, or any kind of information regarding this kind of issue.

```
soundChannel = sound.play(12180000); // DOES NOT PLAY, NO ERRORS
soundChannel = sound.play(12100000); // PLAYS FINE, AND CONTINUES TO PLAY TILL THE END
```

- Sound is fully loaded, before playing.

So anybody have any ideas?

Comment: that usually occurs if you are seeking past the length of the mp3. So that time you gave in milliseconds is 203 minutes, correct?

Comment: Yes. But my mp3 is 4 hours in length :/

Comment: can you send me the mp3 so i can try?

Comment: http://www.m-1.fm/download/audio/podcast/PODSDuDwKkfr.mp3

Comment: Might take some time to load :)

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is not the only track on which i have the same problem, any sound object with more than 203 minutes~ I am unable to seek past that time.

Comment: mkay, I may have to check it tomorrow. I am leaving work in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is interesting... I cannot get it to play past `12173943 milliseconds`. For me, it works up that that exact number, but anything after that, it won't play. My guess is flash allots a certain amount of memory for sounds and that number right there calculates to the maximum amount of memory allotted for that file. Hopefully someone else can chime in. I am using the MP3 provided by Rummer and this was my test code

```
import flash.media.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.load(new URLRequest("podcast.mp3"));
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundLoaded);
sound.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);

function soundLoaded(e:Event):void
{
    channel = sound.play(12173943);
}

function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace(e);
}
```

I'm using Flash CS5.5 and exporting for flash 10.2. I would highly consider splitting your mp3s into sections. The first time my SWF loaded, flash hung for a good 10 seconds before it played because of how large the mp3 is.

=============== AS2 version that works

```
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound();
my_sound.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
{
    if (success)
    {
        my_sound.start(12180);
    } 
};
my_sound.loadSound("podcast.mp3", true);
```

Comment: To add to this, I converted the MP3 to a lower data rate, 32kbps down from 88kbps to see if that number changed. I still can't play past the millisecond stated above. The file is significantly smaller. 58mb down from 220mb. This kind of rules out my theory of memory limitation.

Comment: Well yes :( same problem. I am thinking of swithcing to as2, to try this out. If that would work, i might just integrate a as2 swf to my main player, to play the mix type files.

Comment: I don't see switching to AS2 solving the problem..in fact I'll give it a try right now

Comment: well. I'll be damned..it seeks in as2 just fine..AS2 uses seconds instead of MS..I'll update this post

Comment: It seeks for sure..not sure if that is exactly at 12180 seconds. You can do some time checking to figure it out though

Comment: Well yes as2 works just fine :) so i think i'll have to stick with it at the time. Thanks Ronnie for the help.