# Is there is memory limitation to seek play flash Audio player AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, audio-streaming, flash, flashdevelop

Flash Audio Player: I have an audio file which is 6 hours long, i am not able to seek audio beyond (03:22:54) is there is memory limitation to seek play  beyond this 12173943 milliseconds?

Comment: If it were a memory issue, it would have nothing to do with the seek point and everything to do with the filesize. How big is the file? Additionally, that is no where near the max value for `NetStream.seek()` (`Number`, which has a max value of 1.79e+308). I sincerely doubt it has anything to do with the point you're seeking to. Can you seek to that point in the file in other media players? Can you re-encode to like 56kbps and see if you see the same issues? You may also want to consider breaking the file into smaller chunks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flash Actionscript 3 - sound seeking/playing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782633/flash-actionscript-3-sound-seeking-playing)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some kind of limitation exists. AS3 fails to seek past `12173943 milliseconds`, while AS2 does seek past this point, but with less precision. See [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782633/flash-actionscript-3-sound-seeking-playing) for further details. I'm not aware of any workaround barring splitting the file into chunks smaller than 12000 seconds.